# is there an equivalence relation on orthonormal set?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

According to the definition of orthonormal set : “two vectors **u** and **v** in $R^n$ are said to be orthonormal if they are orthogonal and have length 1, and a set of vectors is said to be an orthonormal set if every vector in the set has length 1 and each pair of distinct vector is orthogonal.”

My question: Is there an equivalence relation on every orthonormal set?
I know orthonormal set is symmetric and transivite because:

1. For any two vectors **v** and **u** in the orthonormal set **S**, if the dot **v** • **u** = **0** then **u** • **v** = **0**

2.For any vectors **u** **v** and **w**  in **S**, if **u** • **v** = **0** and **v** • **w** = **0**, then **u** • **w** is also equal to **0**

But is the set reflexive? Orthogonality can only be applied when there are two vectors, does that mean even though **v** • **v** $\neq$ **0**, there is only one vector(the antecedent is false), the conditional proposition still holds?

Comment: For *any* set you an find an equivalence relation on it. And it doesn't make sense to say that an "orthonormal set is symmetric and transitive" because symmetry and transitivity are notions about relations, not sets.

Comment: I am worried that the relation you've introduced is not even transitive. Basically what you are saying is, geometrically: if $u\bot v$ and $v\bot w$ then $u\bot w$. This is not true - I can imagine three vectors $u,v,w$, both $u$ and $w$ orthogonal to $v$, but having any angle you wish between them. (See the comment below, where the angle is $45^\circ$.)

Comment: let $u = (0,0,1), v = (1,0,0), w = (0,\frac {\sqrt 2}{2},\frac {\sqrt 2}{2})$ then $u\cdot v = 0, v\cdot w = 0,$ and $u\cdot w\ne 0$

Comment: @DougM but if **u** $bull; **v** does not equal to 0 then it doesn’t not satisfy the definition of an orthonormal set? By definition “a set of vectors is said to be an orthonormal set if every vector in the set has length 1 and each pair of distinct vector is orthogonal.” I’m assuming it means if you pick any two vectors from the set **S**, the dot product of the two vector is 0?

Comment: @user296602 what if I change the statement to “the relation on any orthonomoral set is symmetric and transitive” would that make sense?

Comment: @Qwert You seem to be very confused about the definitions here. You have a set of vectors, and then you can *define* two vectors to be related if they satisfy some condition. You haven't given a condition for two vectors to be related, so your question doesn't make sense yet. And there always is at least one equivalence relation (and actually more than one...) on any nonempty set: Define $a \sim b$ iff $a = b$ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for an equivalence relation you must verify $x=x$ but the only vector orthogonal to itself is the zero vector. Thus orthogonality cannot be an equivalence relation.